# No funciona primera clave de array asociativo PHP

Tags: php, array

En PHP, el problema que tengo, es que al recorrer un array asociativo como a continuación, me muestra todos los campos correctamente,

```
foreach ($documentos as $doc) { 
    foreach ($doc as $key => $value) {
        echo $key .' --> '. $value . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

pero al realiza la búsqueda directamente con la calve, el valor de la primera clave no se muestra.

```
foreach ($documentos as $doc){
    echo $doc['nid'];     //Primera clave de mi array asociativo. No se muestra 
    echo $doc['titulo'];  //Segunda clave de mi array asociativo. Si se muestra.
}
```

¿Alguien podría explicarme qué esta pasando y como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Puedes añadir la salida del primer fragmento de código? Revisa la aparicion de espacios al principio y fin de la clave del array

Comment: Deberías compartir el array asociativo en sí también (o al menos una versión mínima con la que reproducir el problema). Lee [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Cuando te encuentres ante estas situaciones, depura tu array mediante  `var_dump($documentos);` o bien mediante `print_r($documentos);`. Verás lo que hay en cada clave/valor del array. Lo cierto es que la clave `nid` como tal no existe, por tanto no se mostrará. Puede que haya otra cosa, o que tenga algún carácter adicional o algo. Eso lo sabrás al depurar.

Comment: Pon tu array para poder verificar lo que sucede